Theme for Bitcoin Stack Exchange
It seems as though Bitcoin Stack Exchange is in top 30 of most trafficated sites: http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic
Most sites in the top 30 have a custom theme. Also people might get thrown away by the "Beta" in the logo.
I was wondering, when can the site get its own theme?

Related: What should our logo and site design look like?

dating more than 2 years ago. wonder why nothing is being done in this regard.

@DavidPerry said in chat on February 8th:

"We get a special design when we leave public beta, which is basically at SE's discretion.
Last I heard we were in the queue for graduation but there were several other sites in front of us and they just have the one designer.
I'll ask again next time I talk to an SE employee" (see Bitcoin Lounge transcript)


great! so there's a process of graduation :) let's hope they do something soon as we're the only ones in the top 30 still in beta.
